# How to navigate to iPod Summary View using iTunes SDK?

Tags: c#, itunes, ipod-touch, itunes-sdk

I'm using the Windows COM SDK with iTunes. I can see my iPod Source, but I want to programmatically "select" it in the iTunes application, so the Device Summary page will be displayed in the iTunes browser area.

How can I do this? Is there a special URL I can use with OpenURL() that can pass in the Device ID or something?